# Simple PUT request to API endpoint

Tags: c#, http, elasticsearch

I'm trying to PUT JSON to the ElasticSearch api in an effort to index/insert a document in an existing index but I can't find any code examples that will actually work. I've looked at httpClient, httpWebRequests and the elastic .net plugin - NEST.

Everything works fine in something like Postman. How would the below translate to C#?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to PUT in ARC(Advanced Rest Client):

[image]

[image]

Comment: so you are  trying to send Put request to an Api using the C# Lagrange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
public void PutAPI(string basicAuth, string json)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("authorization", $"Basic {basicAuth}");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var response = client.PutAsync("https://mydankapi.com/v1/put", new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);              
    }
}
```

Comment: Figured it out, needed `new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result` instead of `new StringContent(json)).Result`

Answer (score 1):

Why didn't NEST meet your requirements? According to their [Getting Started - Indexing](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net#indexing), you can index a document like this:

```
var tweet = new Tweet
{
    Id = 1,
    User = "kimchy",
    PostDate = new DateTime(2009, 11, 15),
    Message = "Trying out NEST, so far so good?"
};

var response = client.Index(tweet, idx => idx.Index("mytweetindex")); //or specify index via settings.DefaultIndex("mytweetindex");
```

All you have to do is to create a POCO class for your document type (`DataMetadata`?) and set the index name to `data_metadata` I believe.